# using base classes on other class constructor C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to understand the observer pattern using C#, first I have an abstract class working as Subject called Stock, then I'm creating a concreteSubject class so I'm going to call it IBM, as the concreteSubject Class is going to inherit from Stock, so I do something like this:

```
class IBM : Stock
{
    // Constructor
    public IBM(string symbol, double price)
      : base(symbol, price)
    {
    }
}
```

what I don't understand is the " : base(symbol, price) " why should I use it? what that means? it looks like its inherit the symbol and price variables, but why if they are declared as parameters on the public IBM function

I get this code from an example that I found in:

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx#_self1

Comment: Note that .NET makes the observer pattern a first-class construct called an event. See this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648108.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It calls base class (`Stock`) constructor. If you look in `Stock` class code it looks like this

```
public class Stock {
    private string _symbol;
    private double _price;

    public Stock(string symbol, double price)  // this constructor is called
    {
         this._symbol = symbol;
         this._price = price;
    }
}
```

Note that it is only constructor in `Stock` class so you must call it explicit in all derived classes by `base(symbol, price)`.

Comment: Ok I see, I need to call the Stock's class contructor from the IBM constructor so I'm passing the parameters to it using the statement ": base(symbol, price)"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This construct means that the `IBM` constructor calls the `Stock` constructor using the same parameters.

There would normally be some extra code in the `IBM` constructor.

There's some examples on the MSDN [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

Comment: Good, now I understand, as my IBM class is inherit from Stock and Stock has a constructor with that two parameters I'm passing the values to the Stock constructor from the IBM constructor that's why I use " : base(symbol, price) " 

I think I have this clear 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just check following resource for better understanding of that construction: [Constructors in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html)